# RxJava CombineLatest debugging

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, combinelatest

I am using RxJava combineLatest operator.

According to the documentation, when subscribing, the first combine emit event will occur only after both observables emits there values, and from this point, it will emit on every emit of each of the Observables.

How can I determine that the first observable emit event has been occurred and it now waits for the second one..

Comment: By logging the observables when they emit their event?

Comment: It is hard as the observables are from different scope of my app.
I don't subscribe the observables at their creation scope. Only in the combineLatest place.  They are behaviour subjects observables.

Comment: Right, in that case, you want to hook up `doOnEac`h to each of the `BehaviourSubjects` that you are combining with `combineLatest`. That way, you're logs will be printed for each of the combined subjects (rather than trying to hookup `doOnEach` to the downstream of `combineLatest`.

Comment: Thanks, I can use both approaches!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `doOnEach` for `Observables` and `Flowables` or `doOnEvent` for `Singles`, `Completables` and `Maybes`. What those operations do is execute some code each time an item is emitted from the source before passing the signal down stream. It's very useful for "injecting" debug/logging code into an RX stream.

See: https://proandroiddev.com/briefly-about-rxjava-logging-20308b013e6d

EDIT:

```
val a = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>().apply {
    onNext(1)
}.doOnEach { EventReporter.d(TAG, it.value?.toString() ?: "") }

val b = BehaviorSubject.create<Int>().apply {
    onNext(2)
}.doOnEach { EventReporter.d(TAG, it.value?.toString() ?: "") }

Observable.combineLatest(listOf(a, b), { args: Collection<Int> -> args}
```

Comment: Thanks! will look on these options!

Comment: I've added a very contrived example code to show you how you can hook up logging to each of the upstream `BehaviourSubjects` before performing combine on them to create a new stream.